# Limit ssh vpn service to one device or connection per user

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

I did set up a ssh vpn on ubuntu server and created a user for that and everything is working fine. So how to limit this service to one device only for that specific created user? I am using password authentication.

Comment: That would depend on the VPN software you are using.

Comment: Does "ssh vpn" mean that you did VPN using `ssh -w`?

Comment: Using ssh port forwarding. Limiting ssh port forwarding to one device only per ssh user.